# Reshape in R with variable name patterns

Tags: r, stata, reshape

I am trying to reproduce the results of a `reshape` in Stata using base R's `reshape` function.

### Stata

```
webuse reshape3, clear
li, clean
// reshape long
reshape long inc@r ue, i(id) j(year)
list, sepby(id) clean
```

This produces, before the `reshape`:

```
. li, clean

       id   sex   inc80r   inc81r   inc82r   ue80   ue81   ue82  
  1.    1     0     5000     5500     6000      0      1      0  
  2.    2     1     2000     2200     3300      1      0      0  
  3.    3     0     3000     2000     1000      0      0      1
```

Note the pattern of the names for the stub `inc`. After the `reshape`, I get:

```
. list, sepby(id) clean

       id   year   sex   incr   ue  
  1.    1     80     0   5000    0  
  2.    1     81     0   5500    1  
  3.    1     82     0   6000    0  
  4.    2     80     1   2000    1  
  5.    2     81     1   2200    0  
  6.    2     82     1   3300    0  
  7.    3     80     0   3000    0  
  8.    3     81     0   2000    0  
  9.    3     82     0   1000    1
```

### R

I run into trouble in R since I don't know how to specify the regular expressiokn required to parse the wide format variable names.

```
library(foreign)
dfReshape3 <- read.dta('http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/reshape3.dta')
reshape(dfReshape3, dir='long', varying=3:8, v.names=c('inc', 'ue'),
        times = c('80', '81', '82'))
```

However, this gives me:

```
     id sex time  inc   ue
1.80  1   0   80 5000 5500
2.80  2   1   80 2000 2200
3.80  3   0   80 3000 2000
1.81  1   0   81 6000    0
2.81  2   1   81 3300    1
3.81  3   0   81 1000    0
1.82  1   0   82    1    0
2.82  2   1   82    0    0
3.82  3   0   82    0    1
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what's read.dta? It doesn't work using base R.

Comment: @arun Apologies. `library(foreign)`.

Comment: A really easy solution is to just remove the trailing "r" from the "inc[0-9]+r" variables. `names(dfReshape3) <- gsub("r$", "", names(dfReshape3))`. Then reshape is pretty straightforward: `reshape(dfReshape3, dir='long', varying=3:8, sep = "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You was really close, just give a list to varying

```
 reshape(dfReshape3, dir='long', varying=list(c(3:5),c(6:8)), v.names=c('inc', 'ue'),times = c('80', '81', '82'))
     id sex time  inc ue
1.80  1   0   80 5000  0
2.80  2   1   80 2000  1
3.80  3   0   80 3000  0
1.81  1   0   81 5500  1
2.81  2   1   81 2200  0
3.81  3   0   81 2000  0
1.82  1   0   82 6000  0
2.82  2   1   82 3300  0
3.82  3   0   82 1000  1
```

Comment: is there any way to create the option `times` in a more general way? Meaning not hardcoding the numbers `c('80', '81', '82')`, but recovering them directly from the data? Thx!

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.GutiérrezVargas you can use a regular expression to extract digits from dataset name. i.e: `unique(stringr::str_extract(nn,"\\d+"))`