# Pivot/Reshape data in R

Tags: r, reshape

**Thank you all for your answers, I thought I was smarter than I am and hoped I would've understood any of it. I think I messed up my visualisation of my data aswell. I have edited my post to better show my sample data. Sorry for the inconvenience, and I truly hope that someone can help me.**

I have a question about reshaping my data. The data collected looks as such:

```
 data <- read.table(header=T, text='
  pid     measurement1     Tdays1     measurement2      Tdays2     measurement3     Tdays3  measurment4    Tdays4 
   1         1356           1435         1483            1405         1563           1374       NA           NA     
   2         943            1848         1173            1818         1300           1785       NA           NA     
   3         1590           185          NA              NA           NA             NA         1585         294    
   4         130            72           443             70           NA             NA         136          79     
   4         140            82           NA              NA           NA             NA         756          89     
   4         220            126          266             124          NA             NA         703          128    
   4         166            159          213             156          476            145        776          166    
   4         380            189          583             173          NA             NA         586          203    
   4         353            231          510             222          656            217        526          240    
   4         180            268          NA              NA           NA             NA         NA           NA       
   4         NA             NA           NA              NA           NA             NA         580          278    
   4         571            334          596             303          816            289        483          371    
  ')
```

Now i would like it to look something like this:

```
PID     Time   Value
 1       1435   1356
 1       1405   1483
 1       1374   1563
 2       1848   943
 2       1818   1173
 2       1785   1300
 3       185    1590
...     ...     ...
```

How would i tend to get there? I have looked up some things about wide to longformat, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Am reletively new to Rstudio and Stackoverflow (if you couldn't tell that already).

Kind regards, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Related [Reshape in R with variable name patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673027/reshape-in-r-with-variable-name-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last edit you asked for a solution that is easy to understand. A very simple approach would be to stack the measurement columns on top of each other and the Tdays columns on top of each other. Although specialty packages make things very concise and elegant, for simplicity we can solve this without additional packages. Standard R has a convenient function aptly named `stack`, which works like this:

```
> exp <-  data.frame(value1 = 1:5, value2 = 6:10)
> stack(exp)
   values    ind
1       1 value1
2       2 value1
3       3 value1
4       4 value1
5       5 value1
6       6 value2
7       7 value2
8       8 value2
9       9 value2
10     10 value2
```

We can stack measurements and Tdays seperately and then combine them via `cbind`:

```
data <- read.table(header=T, text='
  pid     measurement1     Tdays1     measurement2      Tdays2     measurement3     Tdays3  measurement4    Tdays4 
   1         1356           1435         1483            1405         1563           1374       NA           NA     
   2         943            1848         1173            1818         1300           1785       NA           NA     
   3         1590           185          NA              NA           NA             NA         1585         294    
   4         130            72           443             70           NA             NA         136          79     
   4         140            82           NA              NA           NA             NA         756          89     
   4         220            126          266             124          NA             NA         703          128    
   4         166            159          213             156          476            145        776          166    
   4         380            189          583             173          NA             NA         586          203    
   4         353            231          510             222          656            217        526          240    
   4         180            268          NA              NA           NA             NA         NA           NA       
   4         NA             NA           NA              NA           NA             NA         580          278    
   4         571            334          596             303          816            289        483          371    
  ')


cbind(stack(data, c(measurement1, measurement2, measurement3, measurement4)),
      stack(data, c(Tdays1, Tdays2, Tdays3, Tdays4)))
```

Which keeps measurements and Tdays neatly together but leaves us without `pid` which we can add using `rep` to replicate the original `pid` 4 times:

```
result <- cbind(pid = rep(data$pid, 4),
                stack(data, c(measurement1, measurement2, measurement3, measurement4)),
                stack(data, c(Tdays1, Tdays2, Tdays3, Tdays4)))
```

The head of which looks like

```
> head(result)
  pid values          ind values    ind
1   1   1356 measurement1   1435 Tdays1
2   2    943 measurement1   1848 Tdays1
3   3   1590 measurement1    185 Tdays1
4   4    130 measurement1     72 Tdays1
5   4    140 measurement1     82 Tdays1
6   4    220 measurement1    126 Tdays1
```

As I said above, this is not the order you expected and you can try to sort this data.frame, if that is of any concern:

```
result <- result[order(result$pid), c(1, 4, 2)]
names(result) <- c("pid", "Time", "Value")
```

leading to the final result

```
> head(result)
   pid Time Value
1    1 1435  1356
13   1 1405  1483
25   1 1374  1563
37   1   NA    NA
2    2 1848   943
14   2 1818  1173
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! This did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different `pivot_longer()` version.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dw %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -PID, names_to =".value", names_pattern = "(.+)[0-9]")
# A tibble: 9 x 3
    PID     T measurement
  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1     1         100
2     1     4         200
3     1     7          50
4     2     2         150
5     2     5         300
6     2     8          60
7     3     3         120
8     3     6         210
9     3     9          70
```

The `names_to = ".value"` argument creates new columns from column names based on the `names_pattern` argument. The `names_pattern` argument takes a special regex input. In this case, here is the breakdown:

```
(.+)  # match everything - anything noted like this becomes the ".values"
[0-9] # numeric characters - tells the pattern that the numbers 
      # at the end are excluded from ".values". If you have multiple digit 
      # numbers, use [0-9*]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering a dataframe, `df` like the following:

```
     PID T1 measurement1 T2 measurement2 T3 measurement3
     1   1          100  4          200  7           50
     2   2          150  5          300  8           60
     3   3          120  6          210  9           70
```

You can use this solution to get your required dataframe:

```
iters = seq(from = 4, to = length(colnames(df))-1, by = 2)
finalDf = df[, c(1,2,3)]
for(j in iters){
    tobind = df[, c(1,j,j+1)]
    finalDf = rbind(finalDf, tobind)
}

finalDf = finalDf[order(finalDf[,1]),]

print(finalDf)
```

The output of the `print` statement is this:

```
   PID T1 measurement1
1   1  1          100
4   1  4          200
7   1  7           50
2   2  2          150
5   2  5          300
8   2  8           60
3   3  3          120
6   3  6          210
9   3  9           70
```

Comment: in the original `tw` `T1 == 4` is associated with `PID == 2`. In your result `T1 == 4` is associated with `PID == 1`. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Okay, lemme check again.. some issue with sorting

Comment: I had mistakenly pasted the wrong output. The code works correctly, just checked and updated the output.

Comment: Your last edit changed the line numbers, not the PID column of the output. As of now, nothing has changed about my above comment.

Comment: It is because I have considered a similar but different data frame as opposed to what is given in the problem, please see the solution properly. It is bound to give this output, thus no changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
dw %>% 
  pivot_longer(-PID) %>% 
  mutate(name = gsub('^([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)$', '\\1_\\2', name )) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('A', 'B'), sep = '_', convert = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = A, values_from = value)
```

Gives the following output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
    PID     B     T measurement
  <int> <int> <int>       <int>
1     1     1     1         100
2     1     2     4         200
3     1     3     7          50
4     2     1     2         150
5     2     2     5         300
6     2     3     8          60
7     3     1     3         120
8     3     2     6         210
9     3     3     9          70
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `reshape` like below

```
reshape(
  setNames(data, gsub("(\\d+)$", "\\.\\1", names(data))),
  direction = "long",
  varying = 2:ncol(data)
)
```